# async in libgdx to set the screen

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-studio, libgdx

I would like to bring up a loading while loading a screen , for this would make the load async . here's the code :

```
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    loading = new com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("loading.png"))));
    loading.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - loading.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - loading.getHeight() / 2);
    loading.setOrigin(loading.getWidth() / 2, loading.getHeight() / 2);
    loading.setZIndex(1);

    loading.addAction(rotateTo(1440, 20));

    stage.addActor(loading);

    game.setScreen(game.gameScreen);
}
```

what I would do is an async method like this:

asyncmethod()

```
public asyncmethod()
{
    game.setScreen(game.gameScreen);
}

public void show() {
    stage = new Stage();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    loading = new com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("loading.png"))));
    loading.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - loading.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - loading.getHeight() / 2);
    loading.setOrigin(loading.getWidth() / 2, loading.getHeight() / 2);
    loading.setZIndex(1);

    loading.addAction(rotateTo(1440, 20));

    stage.addActor(loading);

    asyncmethod();
}
```

how can I do ? I looked on the website libgdx but I do not understand very well , maybe for my poor english . thank you

Comment: what do you mean "loading a screen" ? do you mean instanciating the screen, loading resources with an assetManager specific for your screen ? something else ?

Comment: Libgdx and threads really don;t go well together. Use the AssetManager instead. There are lots of examples of doing what you want with that.